# "ship" a program (i.e. a program image) to run in another linux computer

Tags: linux-mint, manjaro

I hope this question makes sense. I have a program that I have compiled in an ubuntu machine that works fine. I cannot do the same in a pc with manjaro. Is it possible somehow "to ship" my working program from the ubunto to the manjaro machine?

Somehow I think that with docker I can do this, but many examples in the web seem pretty involved for my task (which it seems to me it's an easy one... hopefully...).

Comment: That's exactly what Docker is for. "The program works on your machine? Great, we'll just ship your machine with it" is a Docker joke. This question will probably get closed because it's not concrete enough, isn't about coding, and is a matter of opinion, but IMHO following a couple of Docker tutorials to learn more about the tool would be a good use of your time.

Comment: Ah! Then I didn't remeber wrong about what was about it. The problem is that reading the tutorials are not so straightforward, and one wouldn't like to spend time in something that doesn't solve the problem. 

I also concur that it's not a programming question; sadly there's not a tag for "soft questions" on the site.